# UIBarButtonItem is shrinked on iPhone 4 inch

Tags: ios, storyboard

Why it happens like this?

[image]

The last one "plus" is just an ADD System Item.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent from such issue?

Comment: What is the buttons container class type? Is it some NavigationBar or ToolBar or what?

Comment: this is `UINavigationBar` with `UIBarButtonItems`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UINavigationBar` the space between items is fixed and you either have to set `rightNavigationItems` array or `leftNavigationItems` array. Then you don't have opportunity to adjust spacing between items yourself. If you have customized view and `UINavigationBar` is not inside a `UINavigationController` then probably you can replace it with `UIToolbar` and add `FlexibleSpace` between each item. It will give you the same result but also it will adjust itself according to screen width.

I added 7 buttons in `interfacebuilder` the upper one is `UINavigationBar` and lower one is `UIToolbar` with `FlexibleSpace` item between each `UIBarButtonItem`

[image: I added 7 buttons in <code>interfacebuilder</code> the upper one is <code>UINavigationBar</code> and lower one is <code>UIToolbar</code> with <code>FlexibleSpace</code> item between each <code>UIBarButtonItem</code>]

And This is what I got the result on iPhone4 Simulator

[image: And This is what I got the result on iPhone4 Simulator]

Comment: So you suggest to replace navigation bar with uitoolbar?;) I do it later

Comment: Yes, that worked for me at least. I hope it will help you too :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the space for the "add" item is a bit smaller and leads the item to internally used textfield less space making the text shrink to fit size, its only a guess.

Maybe/surly you can solve the issue using a custom item, but this would obviously not explain what is going on...